# Exporta de SQL para Excel e realizar Download erro SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, query

Fiz esta Query

```
MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = 28 or id_conta = 29 or id_conta = 30 or id_conta = 36")
```

Esta Query me retorna todas as contas que contenham os IDs: 28, 29, 30 e 36.

Poderiam me dar uma dica de como realizo o código em Ruby para que seja Exportado de SQL para Excel e realizado Download?

Eu fiz assim:

```
> require 'csv' CSV.generate do |csv| csv <<
> ["headers","describing","the data"] mysql.query("MtDispositivo.where
> "id_conta = 28 or id_conta = 29 or id_conta = 30 or id_conta = 36).each { |row| csv << row }  
end
```

Está correto?

---

**Atualizado:**

Consegui criar o trecho do código em Ruby.

```
def mt_dispositivo_xls

    mt_dispositivo = MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = 28 or id_conta = 29 or id_conta = 30 or id_conta = 36")

    send_data mt_dispositivo.to_xls(:except => [:id_conta]), content_type 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'mt_dispositivo_xls'
end
```

> Só que estou tendo este erro de Sintaxe quando texto no Console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
send_mt_dispositivo.to_xls(:except => [:id_conta]), content_type 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'mt_dispositivo_xls'
SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
...to_xls(:except => [:id_conta]), content_type 'application/vn...
```

Podem me ajudar nessa?

Answer (score 0):

Não parece ser um problema na query, olhando para a documentação do `send_data` suponho que tenha faltado o `:`, mude isto:

```
send_data mt_dispositivo.to_xls(:except => [:id_conta]), content_type 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'mt_dispositivo_xls'
```

Para isto

```
send_data mt_dispositivo.to_xls(:except => [:id_conta]), content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'mt_dispositivo_xls'
```

No entanto talvez `content_type` seja alguma versão mais antiga, aparentemente hoje (rails 5.1.1) é apenas `type`, então use assim:

```
send_data mt_dispositivo.to_xls(:except => [:id_conta]), type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'mt_dispositivo_xls'
```

Documentação: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html